# Can a Pyautogui code which includes keystrokes and mouse pointers run in the background inside a VM?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to run a code which has keystrokes and mouse pointer movements to run inside a VM (While the VM is not logged in, i.e backend execution through a task scheduler). Is this possible in Pyautogui?

Right now when i try to schedule the task at a particular time and not login into the VM during that time, the code fails telling it is not able to find the login page. But the login page is actually loaded.

The same code works seamlessly when i login into the VM and run. I am not sure why this is not working when I dont login into the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way by which you can let pyautogui work as well as do all your work at the same time with no VMs.

actully you cant run it in background, but you can do the thing mention above by these steps:-

First, you need 2 keyboards and mouse attached on your windows computer.

then install this application called mouse mux. https://www.mousemux.com/

Then turn on 'multiplex input' and multiple keyboard option.

Now you will be able to use 2 mouse and keyboards at the same time.

put pyautogui in side my side view, and the first mouse and keyboard will be
controlled by pyautogui and you can use 2nd mouse and keyboard to do something else.

by this way you dont need a VM at all!

Note:_

Read the image carefully!.

[image]